# analyse_text() function of the Java Lexer in Pygments

Tags: python, lexer, pygments

I have written the following code using pygments to get info on a string:

```
from pygments.lexers.jvm import JavaLexer
import pygments.lexers.jvm

t = 'float s = 0.5; System.out.println("Hello World");'
lexer = JavaLexer()
lexer.analyse_text(t)
```

I get a value of 0.0 as a result of running this code while it should be something greater than 0 since quite a lot of the code is java-specific. Where exactly am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely nothing :) The `analyze_text` method is useful when there are multiple languages sharing the same file extension, in which case the lexers should implement it properly. The [`JavaLexer`](https://github.com/pygments/pygments/blob/5bd2a84bc1db0120828606c900a14276414fecdc/pygments/lexers/jvm.py#L27) has no `analyze_text` implemented, so it returns 0 by default. Hope that explains it!